# objective-c: converting date string into day of the week + month name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, datetime

A beginner's problem, but I was wondering if anyone could help me with this:

I need to set four strings according to a string which contains a certain date (e.g. @"Apr 7, 2011"):

- a string which will take the day of the week (abbreviated: Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun): e.g. `@"Thu"`
- a string which will take the day, e.g. `@"7"`
- a string which will take the month, e.g. `@"April"`
- and a string which will take the year, e.g. `@"2011"`

---

So far, I found this:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:118800];

NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];

NSLog(@"Date for locale %@: %@",
      [[dateFormatter locale] localeIdentifier], [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
// Output:
// Date for locale en_US: Jan 2, 2001
```

---

So this would give me a certain formatted date. I was wondering, however, how I can access certain parts of this date. There is the - (NSArray *)weekdaySymbols but I have no idea how to work this one and the documentation is quite frugal.

Any hints from calendar experts would be very welcome.

---

**EDIT:**

I guess this is part of the solution:

```
    NSLocale *gbLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
NSString *gbFormatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EdMMM" options:0 locale:gbLocale];
NSLog(@"gbFormatterString: %@", gbFormatString);
// Output: gbFormatterString: EEE d MMM, e.g. Thu 7 Apr
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

n.evermind,

You're going to need something like this:

```
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyy"];
    date = [formatter dateFromString:@"Apr 7, 2011"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSInteger units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:date];
    NSInteger year = [components year];
    NSInteger month=[components month];       // if necessary
    NSInteger day = [components day];
    NSInteger weekday = [components weekday]; // if necessary

    NSDateFormatter *weekDay = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [weekDay setDateFormat:@"EEE"];

    NSDateFormatter *calMonth = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [calMonth setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];

    NSLog(@"%@ %i %@ %i", [weekDay stringFromDate:date], day, [calMonth stringFromDate:date], year );
```

output

```
2011-04-07 12:49:23.519 test[7296:207] Apr 07, 2011
2011-04-07 12:49:23.521 test[7296:207] Thu 7 April 2011
```

Cheers, Jordan

Comment: Just one other thing: how do I actually get today's date? I.e. in your example it's static date = [formatter dateFromString:@"Apr 7, 2011"]; Thanks for your help!

Comment: NSDate date = [NSDate date]; will give you today's date. In which case, you don't need the first NSDateFormatter in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a Look on [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks, but the documentation is quite hard going. I guess I need - (NSArray *)weekdaySymbols but have no idea of how to use this in my context.

Answer (score 0):

@n.evermind

You should actually look at [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) and specifically the `- components:fromDate` method which gives you the [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDateComponents) object which has all the peices you want.