# How to format the string date and time to Tuesday 4 December 2012,5:30 PM

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsdateformatter

I have a small doubt regarding the conversion of a date and time string to (`Tuesday 4 December 2012,5:30 PM`) in `Objective c`

```
NSString *str = [detailsdict objectForKey:@"doc_appointments_Time"];
//time format is 5:30:00 PM

NSString *dateandtime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",[detailsdict objectForKey:@"doc_appointments_Date"],str];
//date format is 10/25/2016

cell.detailTextLabel.text=dateandtime;
```

Comment: then what you want date and time like this format `Tuesday 4 December 2012,5:30 PM` ?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024491/convert-string-date-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [objective-c: converting date string into day of the week + month name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583984/objective-c-converting-date-string-into-day-of-the-week-month-name)

Answer (score 3):

For that first you need to merge both the date and time string after that use `NSDateFormatter` to generate date in a format you want.

```
NSString *stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[detailsdict objectForKey:@"doc_appointments_Date"], [detailsdict objectForKey:@"doc_appointments_Time"]];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:stringDate];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE d MMMM yyyy,h:mm a"];
NSString *formattedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```